# Under what conditions is a flash video fallback required?

Tags: video

If you prepare both a mp4 and ogv video formats, under what conditions will the video still be unviewable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `<video>` element works only in HTML5 browsers, so Flash will be required for IE6-8.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=video

Video won't be playable at all in pre-HTML5 browsers that don't have recent Flash (10 or later) installed, since older Flash versions didn't support H.264 codec. That includes featurephones with Flash Lite.

You also need to be careful about exact codec you use in the MP4 file, since some devices can only play H.264 baseline profile, and may not support more advanced H.264 profiles.

Comment: Fantastic info, thanks! So if using flash as a fallback for IE8, makes sense to encode a 3rd On2VPC version

Comment: I think for the desktop Flash you can assume H.264 support, as this Flash version is still maintained and updated.